# Parse and iterate through JSON string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json

This could be so simple but I am new at Objective-c and I can't find a way how to do this, I have a string that looks like this:

```
[
 {quantity: 2, product: "CHEESEBURGER", price: 14.44, extraingredients: [{name:'extra sos', price:3.00}]},
 {quantity: 1, product: "FANTA", price: 14.40},
 {quantity: 1, product: "CHICKEN POKE BOWL", price: 14.50}
]
```

Now I need to parse this string and to iterate through each object and also to iterate through each extraingredients array.

I did some research and what i found for parsing is this:

```
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                            JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                            error:&e];
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As quoted above, the string is not valid JSON. The keywords (e.g. `quantity`, `product`) must be in double quotes, and the string value of `name` must also be double quotes. Making the changes to the string, the `NSJSONSerialization` class works:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"quantity\": 2, \"product\": \"CHEESEBURGER\", \"price\": 14.44, "\
                        "\"extraingredients\": [{\"name\":\"extra sos\", \"price\":3.00}]}, "\
                        "{\"quantity\": 1, \"product\": \"FANTA\", \"price\": 14.40}, "\
                        "{\"quantity\": 1, \"product\": \"CHICKEN POKE BOWL\", \"price\": 14.50}]";

NSError *e;
NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                  error:&e];
```

Comment: you are right but how to iterate through whole array and how to access properties like in javascript dot name of the property (.name or .product) and then also if it has sub array inside for instance extraingredients array